# Pass class as a function parameter in client program WCF C#

Tags: wcf, class, object

I have written a wcf program where I have an class library where I declared the function which contains a class as a parameter.

I accessed that function in a client program but I don't know how to pass the class to that function. I will write the code below.

1. I have an interface which contains basic function declaration
2. In the class library there is another class it is implementing the interface. That interface contains a method which takes a class as parameter.

That class which is parameter contains properties.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICarDetails
{
    [OperationContract]
    string updateCarDetails(Car c);
}

public class CarDetails : ICarDetails
{
    public string updateCarDetails(Car c)
    {
        //some operations and initilizations
        string example = Car.carno = "1234";
        return "success";
    }
}

Public class Car
{
    private string carno;
    private string carModel;

    public string CARNO
    {
        get{ return carno; }
        set{ carno = value; }

    }

    public string CARMODEL
    {
        get{ return carModel; }
        set{ carModel = value; }
    }
}
```

3) I will get access this function in myclient program where I consume. While consuming I need to send a class right? If so how can I send a class.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CarDetailsserviceClient client = new CarDetailsserviceClient();
        string abc = client.updateCarDetails(); // This shows error
    }
}

public class carclient
{
    public string carno = "6789";
}
```

I want to send this client class carclient to wcf service function updatecardetails.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't pass a class, you must pass an object of that class. Create new object :

```
Car carclient = new Car() { CARNO = "6789" };
```

Then, pass it in argument :

```
string abc = client.updateCarDetails(carclient);
```

`Car` must be include in the `DataContract` like this :

```
[DataContract]
public class Car
{
    private String carno;
    private String carModel;

    [DataMember]
    public String CARNO
    {
        get { return this.carno; }
        set { this.carno = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public String CARMODEL
    {
        get { return this.carModel; }
        set { this.carModel = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP's problem is not that they don't understand how to instantiate an instance of a type, but that the type in question is not available to them in the calling code. In your solution, Car will not be defined.

Comment: Your answer still does not provide a solution. How is the OP going to get access to the Car type? Additionally the first few lines of your answer do not address the question.

Comment: Hi All Thanks for all your suggestions. Here  my main intention is how to pass a class or object as parameter.Its okay i need to add data contracts. Xaruth understand well. I done this its executed well. Thanks Xaruth.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark your Car type with the [DataContract and DataMember](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attributes before you can pass it across the service boundary:

```
[DataContract]
public class Car
{
    private string carno;
    private string carModel;

    [DataMember]
    public string CARNO
    {
        get{ return carno; }
        set{ carno = value; }

    }

    [DataMember]
    public string CARMODEL
    {
        get{ return carModel; }
        set{ carModel = value; }
    }
}
```

If you do this then regenerate your service client, you will find you have access to the Car type from you calling code and you won't need to define your own type on the client side.